# Dell Laptop Inspiron 17" 3793 brandnew - after Ubuntu install always boot failure to grub

Tags: boot, dell

On a brandnew DELL Laptop I installed Ubuntu 20.10. Diskcheck was ok, installation said it was successful and complete.
But after reboot it shows either the terminal saying "grub >"or it says "error:can´t find hwmatch...command failed...you need to load the kernel first".

So I made a new installation with Ubuntu 20.04, fresh install by erasing the whole disc, and the install process ran smoothly saying everything is fine.
But after reboot it shows either the terminal saying "grub >"or it says "error:can´t find hwmatch...command failed...you need to load the kernel first".

Well I did it two times each, but no success.

Can someone tell me where the problem is? This laptop is Ubuntu-certified, I looked that up before installation.

Answer (score 2):

its a problem with tpm-module

this:

```
sudo cp /etc/grub.d/40_custom /etc/grub.d/06_notpm
sudo bash -c 'echo "rmmod tpm" >> /etc/grub.d/06_notpm'
sudo update-grub
```

thanks a lot to:  @Dayworker (from dell-forum.de)